# cannot create directory using ODIExportMaster tool

Tags: linux, oracle-data-integrator

I am using ODIExportMaster tool in a package. The tool will create a zip file and save on server. The server is Linux machine and agent also reside on the same system as that of odi.
The code runs fine for dev and test environment. but its giving error as **'Can not create directory'**  on production server.

The user has same rights in all the environment.
Kindly guide me if anybody have any idea.

/Regards

Comment: Can any body suggest me some way to find out appropriate reason behind this as why i am facing this issue in an environment while the same code running properly on other?

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you are executing the package from client machinei, isn't it?

if so, please check with your production system Admin if you have access to the user where your client is installed.

or if you are running scenario on server it self instead of client machine, still if it is giving error try to understand why is it trying to create directory?
OR if it is directing a wrong error.